Accessing ActiveMQ Classic web console for an instance installed in a remote server
I have installed ActiveMQ Classic in a VM in Azure with an IP address X.X.X.X, where another web application is also running. So it is a remote server.
Now, I need to get access to the ActiveMQ web console.
I am typing the URL X.X.X.X:8161/admin, but I'm getting the error message:
This site can't be reached

So, I think this error is because the web console is listening to the IP address 127.0.0.1 (i.e. localhost) and not the IP address X.X.X.X of the server.
I tried changing the properties host and port of jetty.xml like this:
    <bean id="jettyPort" class="org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsolePort" init-method="start">
        <!-- the default port number for the web console -->
        <property name="host" value="X.X.X.X"/>
        <property name="port" value="8161"/>
    </bean>

But after making this change I cannot start ActiveMQ since when I type the command sh activemq console I get the error:
Cannot assign the requested address

The version of ActiveMQ is 5.15.0.
Here is the log of the error:
INFO: Using java '/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201-amd64/bin/java'
INFO: Starting in foreground, this is just for debugging purposes (stop process by pressing CTRL+C)
INFO: Creating pidfile /data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0//data/activemq.pid
Java Runtime: Oracle Corporation 1.8.0_201 /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_201-amd64/jre
Heap sizes: current=62976k  free=58715k  max=932352k
JVM args: -Xms64M -Xmx1G -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0//conf/login.config -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0//tmp -Dactivemq.classpath=/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0//conf:/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0//../lib/: -Dactivemq.home=/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0/ -Dactivemq.base=/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0/ -Dactivemq.conf=/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0//conf -Dactivemq.data=/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0//data
Extensions classpath:
[/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0/lib,/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0/lib/camel,/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0/lib/optional,/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0/lib/web,/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0/lib/extra]
ACTIVEMQ_HOME: /data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0
ACTIVEMQ_BASE: /data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0
ACTIVEMQ_CONF: /data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0/conf
ACTIVEMQ_DATA: /data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0/data
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@5442a311: startup date [Fri Jul 26 09:13:44 UTC 2024]; root of context hierarchy
INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0/data/kahadb]
INFO | KahaDB is version 6
INFO | PListStore:[/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0/data/localhost/tmp_storage] started
INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.0 (localhost, ID:XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX-XX-43925-1721985228178-0:1) is starting
INFO | Listening for connections at: tcp://XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX-XX:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
INFO | Connector openwire started
INFO | Listening for connections at: amqp://XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX-XX:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
INFO | Connector amqp started
INFO | Listening for connections at: stomp://XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX-XX:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
INFO | Connector stomp started
INFO | Listening for connections at: mqtt://XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX-XX:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
INFO | Connector mqtt started
WARN | ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@68df9280{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /
INFO | Listening for connections at ws://XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX-XX:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600
INFO | Connector ws started
INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.0 (localhost, ID:XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX-XX-43925-1721985228178-0:1) started
INFO | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org
WARN | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 22 mb). The data directory: /data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0/data/kahadb only has 93072 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 93072 mb
INFO | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://X.X.X.X:8161/
INFO | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://X.X.X.X:8161/api/jolokia/
INFO | Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
INFO | No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
INFO | jolokia-agent: Using policy access restrictor classpath:/jolokia-access.xml
WARN | FAILED ServerConnector@5fe8b721{HTTP/1.1}{X.X.X.X:8161}: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_201]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)[:1.8.0_201]
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)[:1.8.0_201]
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)[:1.8.0_201]
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)[:1.8.0_201]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)[jetty-all-9.2.22.v20170606.jar:9.2.22.v20170606]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_201]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_201]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_201]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_201]
at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:269)[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingBean.invokeWithTargetException(MethodInvokingBean.java:119)[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(MethodInvokingFactoryBean.java:106)[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)[xbean-spring-4.2.jar:4.2]
at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)[xbean-spring-4.2.jar:4.2]
at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67)[activemq-spring-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)[activemq-broker-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)[activemq-broker-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87)[activemq-console-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)[activemq-console-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:154)[activemq-console-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)[activemq-console-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)[activemq-console-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_201]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_201]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_201]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_201]
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)[activemq.jar:5.15.0]
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)[activemq.jar:5.15.0]
WARN | FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@36b6964d: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)[activemq.jar:5.15.0]
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)[activemq.jar:5.15.0]
WARN | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'invokeStart' defined in class path resource [jetty.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
INFO | Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.0 (localhost, ID:XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX-XX-43925-1721985228178-0:1) is shutting down
INFO | Connector openwire stopped
INFO | socketQueue interrupted - stopping
INFO | Could not accept connection during shutdown  : {}
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)[:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2088)[:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)[:1.8.0_201]
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportServer$1.run(TcpTransportServer.java:479)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_201]
INFO | Connector amqp stopped
INFO | Connector stomp stopped
INFO | socketQueue interrupted - stopping
INFO | Could not accept connection during shutdown  : {}
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)[:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2088)[:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)[:1.8.0_201]
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportServer$1.run(TcpTransportServer.java:479)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_201]
INFO | Connector mqtt stopped
INFO | socketQueue interrupted - stopping
INFO | Could not accept connection during shutdown  : {}
java.lang.InterruptedException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)[:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2088)[:1.8.0_201]
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)[:1.8.0_201]
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransportServer$1.run(TcpTransportServer.java:479)[activemq-client-5.15.0.jar:5.15.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)[:1.8.0_201]
INFO | Connector ws stopped
INFO | PListStore:[/data/temenos/activemq/apache-activemq-5.15.0/data/localhost/tmp_storage] stopped
INFO | Stopping async queue tasks
INFO | Stopping async topic tasks
INFO | Stopped KahaDB
INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.0 (localhost, ID:XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX-XX-43925-1721985228178-0:1) uptime 4.854 seconds
INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.0 (localhost, ID:XXX-XXX-XXXXXXX-XX-43925-1721985228178-0:1) is shutdown
INFO | Closing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@5442a311: startup date [Fri Jul 26 09:13:44 UTC 2024]; root of context hierarchy
WARN | Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@5442a311: startup date [Fri Jul 26 09:13:44 UTC 2024]; root of context hierarchy
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)[activemq.jar:5.15.0]
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)[activemq.jar:5.15.0]
ERROR | Failed to load: class path resource [activemq.xml], reason: Error creating bean with name 'invokeStart' defined in class path resource [jetty.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'invokeStart' defined in class path resource [jetty.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)[activemq.jar:5.15.0]
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)[activemq.jar:5.15.0]
ERROR: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'invokeStart' defined in class path resource [jetty.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute start task. Reason: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'invokeStart' defined in class path resource [jetty.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'invokeStart' defined in class path resource [jetty.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
ERROR: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'invokeStart' defined in class path resource [jetty.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'invokeStart' defined in class path resource [jetty.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address

Can someone help me to understand the issue and its solution?

What version of ActiveMQ Classic are you using? Is there a stack-trace associated with the error message? If so, can you share it?

This answer may be helpful.

That is a low level error from the Java JVM itself, Jetty is barely involved in this.
Basically it means that your configuration of the IP and Port combination isn't valid for that machine.
The IP might not be mapped to a local network interface, or the IP is valid and the Port specified is in use by some other process.
See past answers for details.

Cannot assign requested address using ServerSocket.socketBind
nifi can't assign requested address

